# Cannot disable multi touch on Uitable View (ios7)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have an  problem that i use custom cell for `UITableView`, when I tap more than one finger (2 fingers or more) on my `tableview` it had many problems some of my `labels` on each cells (to display information) lost texts (it's empty). So that I try to disable multi touch on my table, but it's not affect. I try to add `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;` or `tableView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;` into `cellForRowAtIndexPath or didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. But nothing work. Please help me to find out solution.

Thank you!
Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = indexPath.row;

@synchronized (self) {
    if (row == [voicemailItems count]) {
        // User selected the blank rows
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        // Blank out the play button on previous selected row
        [self deselect];

        return;
    }
}

if (selectedRowIndexPath != nil) {
    if (row == selectedRowIndexPath.row) {
        // Selecting the same row twice will play the voicemail
        if (streaming == NO) {
            if (calling == NO) {
                // Play the voicemail
                [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(playVoicemailAction:) userInfo:indexPath repeats:NO];
            }

            return;
        }
        else {
            // Streaming VM
            if ([self isCallInProgress] == YES) {
                [ScreenUtils errorAllert:@"Cannot play voicemail while call is in progress." type:kUINotice delegate:self];
            }
            else {
                if (![self isVoicemailNotification:selectedRowIndexPath.row]) {
                    // Stream the voicemail
                    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(playVoicemailAction:) userInfo:indexPath repeats:NO];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // Selecting a different row
        [self shutdownPlayer];
        [self cancel];

        // Blank out the play button on previous selected row
        [self deselect];
    }
}

selectedRowIndexPath = indexPath;

// Enable Call Back button 
// Don't enable if private, etc.
btnCallBack.enabled = ([self canCallBack:row] &&
                       !calling &&
                       ([self isCallInProgress] == NO) &&
                       ![self isVoicemailNotification:selectedRowIndexPath.row]);

// Enable and Delete button
btnDelete.enabled = YES;

// Select the cell
VoicemailCell * cell = (VoicemailCell*)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell select:YES playing:[self isPlaying] stream:streaming];
[tblView setNeedsDisplay];

//[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code.

Comment: you should work on the cause — not the symptoms.

Comment: Why would you call methods that affect the tableView from within delegate methods?  They should be called when allocate/initialize the tableview and once only.

Comment: Your problem is multiple cells get selected same time?

Comment: You can put this two lines in viewdidload method  tableView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO; and tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO; try like this..

Comment: @kalyanipuvvada puvvada: it's not work

Comment: once try to disable multitouch for self.view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after many tries, I find out that I need to add the follow code at the end of didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it helps me!

```
cell.contentView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
cell.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

@try this

```
[cell setExclusiveTouch:YES]
```

Comment: I use custom cell for my tableview, when I tap on cell it catch this action and then respond by change text color of label, show button(I do it at custom's file)...But when I use more than one finger to touch very fast on table view, I think it can not change as fast as touch's action. So that it's work wrong, I think I have to let the fist tap have enough time to finished it's work before do the action of second tap.So how to do that? Hop you can understand what I mean.Thanks.

Comment: [cell setExclusiveTouch:YES]  disable multiply touch at a time on your cells, did you try this ??

Comment: yep! I placed it at cellForRowAtIndexPath but it's doesn't work.