# In ios7 tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is not called

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I meagrate my project to adjust ios7 while I encountered a strange problem : the delegate method "tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" is not called in ios7 ,it works well in prior ios version.I was wonder if some specific property be changed in ios7
Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [self.tableView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)sender didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [sender deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    _currentContact = [contactArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([_currentContact.accountNPC hasPrefix:@"0"]) {
        isContactToNPC = NO;
    }else{
        isContactToNPC = YES;
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed to UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource in .h file ?

Comment: Are you using custom cells in UITableViewCell ?

Comment: @NANNAV : Does it matter that he uses customcell or default tableviewcell? because in both the condition didSelectRowAtIndexPath must be called.

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper if custom cell have tapgesture it not called

Comment: @passol Is this occurs only in iOS 7 ?

Comment: @Xman  Yes,it declare delegate and datasource and implement it,only set **[cell setExclusiveTouch:YES]** it works well

Comment: Are u refreshing UITableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method? If you are doing so, it resets the state of the tableview cells .. you have to write your own logic to handle that

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your viewController.h file

```
 <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDatasource>
```

also connect the tableview's delegate and datasource to the File's Owner of .xib

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry,I found the answer 
I just need set

```
[cell setExclusiveTouch:YES]
```

Tks @[abhishekkharwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356068/abhishekkharwar) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18826264/2396477