# How to change `UIImageView` in custom cell in `UITableView`

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `UIImageView` in custom cell in `UITableView` and in want to change that image in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

It's working with `UIImageView` outside the `UITableView`, but not working inside it.

I am using this code..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *string = [[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    ExpandCell *cell = [self.menuTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    UIImage *image;

    if ([string isEqualToString:@"News"]) {

        if ([[self.viewImage image] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow.png"]]) {
            NSLog(@"down");
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"up-arrow.png"];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"up");
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow.png"];
        }

        cell.imgExpand.image = image;
        self.viewImage.image = image;

    }
}
```

**How can I fix that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assign a tag number to your `UIImageView` (say 10).
Then write this code in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *yourImageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:10];//Replace yourImageView with the name of your UIImageView on custom cell

//--------- Your code ------
NSString *str = [[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
UIImage *image;

if ([str isEqualToString:@"News"])
{

    if ([[self.viewImage image] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow.png"]]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"down");
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"up-arrow.png"];

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"up");
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down-arrow.png"];
    }

    [yourImageView setImage:image];
    [self.viewImage setImage:image];
}
```

I think this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following line creates a new cell:

```
ExpandCell *cell = [self.menuTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Change it to:

```
ExpandCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This will give you the currently visible cell you just selected.

Answer (score 0):

Add this command `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` at the end of **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: This is not related to the question being asked? This should be posted as a comment, not an answer. Besides, the OP might not want the selection cleared.

Comment: I ever have the same problem at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825733/cannot-disable-multi-touch-on-uitable-view-ios7] .So that I think, it maybe helpful as it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After you set a new image,you can use function:

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

reload the cell you changed.